# Using Subqueries with FIND_IN_SET function in MariaDB

Tags: mysql

I have the following set up:

[clients]: `id` (ai), `name` (text), `regions` (text);
[regions]: `id` (ai - related to `region_id` in [municipalities]), `name` (text);
[municipalities]: `id` (ai - related to `municipality_id` in [postals]), name (text), `region_id` (int);
[postals]: `id` (ai), `name` (text), `municipality_id` (int).

- all the id's are primary keys

The `regions` column in [clients] contains a string like "1", "1,2" or "1,3,7".

Now, the general idea is the someone enters a specific value for postal name, and the client name is returned when the postal code falls into the specific region. Each municipality belongs to a specific region and each postal code belongs to a specific municipality. A client can work within multiple regions.

I have the following query:

```
select name from clients where find_in_set((select region_id from municipalities where id = (select municipality_id from postals where name = "string")),(select regions from clients)) != 0
```

But I keep getting #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row, and I don't know why. The searched string should only return 1 municipality_id, which in turn should only return 1 region_id, which should only be found once in the `regions` string in the [clients] table.

What am I missing here?

Comment: find_in_set is not for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work, though I have not tested it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name
FROM clients AS c
JOIN municipalities AS m
  ON FIND_IN_SET(m.region_id, c.regions)
JOIN postals AS p
  ON m.id = p.municipality_id
WHERE p.name = 'string';
```

This is not the intended use of FIND_IN_SET(). That function is supposed to be used to match values in MySQL's [SET data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html). It works for matching comma-separated strings too, but it's not a good use case for SQL.

Using FIND_IN_SET() against a comma-separated list is bound to do a table-scan, so it can't be optimized with an index. If you want your query to have better performance, you should not store multivalued attributes as a comma-separated string.

For other bad effects of using comma-separated strings, see my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

A multivalued attribute belongs in a child table, with one value per row, and a reference to the municipality. Then you can do your search with joins, and you have an opportunity to create indexes to optimize the query.

Comment: Thanks. I just found (while you posted this) that swapping out the subquery intended to build the haystack for the name of column (`regions`) gave me what I was looking for (though I have tested in thoroughly yet).

Regardless, thanks for the advice and I'll look into your suggestions.